# How do I mark URL's to appear as href's when viewed via the eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse

// Refer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal

I have a snippet like this in my java source code, viewed via the Eclipse editor. How do I make this appear as a href, so that users can just click on it, instead of doing a cut-n-paste.

Is is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It`s appeared as URL, when you hover on it with Ctrl pressed. Currently it works in PDT under WIN.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the user's editor, if it's able to interpret url's inside comments. At least for Eclipse, I couldn't find a plugin that does this for you. You might need to write your own or ask the Eclipse community for one.